Latency issue using TextEmbeddingModel
I'm using Vertex AI's TextEmbeddingModel to calculate embeddings, and the first call shows significantly higher latency than the rest, likely due to caching. However, this isn't context-caching, and sdk_encode is being called one at a time. How can I warm up the system to reduce the initial delay?
    import time
    import google.generativeai as genai
    from vertexai.language_models import TextEmbeddingInput, TextEmbeddingModel
    base_model_name = "text-embedding-004"
    EMBED_TASK_TYPE = "RETRIEVAL_QUERY"
    
    text_embedding_model = TextEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained(base_model_name)
    model = TextEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained(base_model_name)
    
    def sdk_encode( text):
            inputs = [TextEmbeddingInput(text.lower(), EMBED_TASK_TYPE) ]
            kwargs = {}
            embeddings = model.get_embeddings(inputs, **kwargs)
            text_embeddings = [embedding.values for embedding in embeddings]
            return text_embeddings[0] if len(text_embeddings) == 1 else text_embeddings
    
    queries = ["I want to take pto Monday", "I want to take pto Tuesday", "I want to take pto Friday"]
    for i in range(3): 
        query = queries[i]
        start_time = time.time()
        sdk_encode(query)
        end_time = time.time()
        sdk_delay = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Vertext SDK Latency for {query}: {sdk_delay}")

Output:
Vertext SDK Latency for I want to take pto Monday: 1.3506088256835938
Vertext SDK Latency for I want to take pto Tuesday: 0.12767696380615234
Vertext SDK Latency for I want to take pto Friday: 0.12481999397277832


I have not been able to replicate your finding (that the first call to the embedding model takes longer), I am afraid. I tried it in a Colab notebook, for reference.
However, I have noticed that there doesn't seem to be any reason to loop over the queries in the way that you are doing. I found that when you are embedding just three strings, almost all the latency seems to come from the repeated calls.
From experimentation, nothing is stopping you from sending all your queries to VertexAI as part of the same statement. Judging from the fact that the response comes back no slower than any of your individual function calls, the library must be batching queries up and handling them simultaneously.
Try this:
import time
import google.generativeai as genai
from vertexai.language_models import TextEmbeddingInput, TextEmbeddingModel

model = TextEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained("text-embedding-004")

inputs = [TextEmbeddingInput(text.lower(), "RETRIEVAL_QUERY") for text in queries]

st = time.time()
embeddings = [e.values for e in model.get_embeddings(inputs)]
et = time.time()

print(f"Vertex SDK Latency: {et - st}")

Presumably, as you add more strings to the batch you will see slowdowns (as latency starts to become dominated by processing time, rather than I/O).
If this becomes a problem it may be worth experimenting with different VertexAI pretrained models - some may be faster at generating embeddings than others.

The point was that in our application, queries come one at a time and not as a list. Once given as a list, I noticed the first embedding is always longer than the others, question is why?  bc if I can fix that, then in my application, which is only one query at a time, the embedding will have lower latency. What sort if of init or warmup I need to do?

As I say in my answer, I can't replicate your finding. It seems, then, that this is not an issue in general, but rather with your specific system. IMO you shouldn't look for a general solution to a specific problem. Perhaps try your original code in a Colab notebook or some other easily-set-up alternative environment and see whether you have the same issue? This might at least yield some clues.

You can utilize several strategies with Vertex AI to minimize latency and enhance the responsiveness of your applications:
Choose the right model for your use case
Currently we have 9 Embeddings for Text model versions namely:

Text-embedding-preview-0815

Text-embedding-004

Text-multilingual-embedding-002

Text-embedding-preview-0409

Text-multilingual-embedding-preview-0409

textembedding-gecko@003

textembedding-gecko@002

textembedding-gecko-multilingua@001

textembedding-gecko@001


Carefully evaluate your requirements regarding speed and output quality to choose the model that best aligns with your use case.
Optimize prompt and output length
The number of tokens in both your input prompt and expected output directly impacts processing time. Minimize your token count to reduce latency.

Craft clear and concise prompts that effectively convey your intent without unnecessary details or redundancy. Shorter prompts reduce your time to first token.

Use system instructions to control the length of the response. Instruct the model to provide concise answers or limit the output to a specific number of sentences or paragraphs. This strategy can reduce your time to last token.

Adjust the temperature. Experiment with the temperature parameter to control the randomness of the output. Lower temperature values can lead to shorter, more focused responses, while higher values can result in more diverse, but potentially longer, outputs. For more information, see temperature in the model parameters reference.

Restrict output by setting a limit. Use the max_output_tokens parameter to set a maximum limit on the length of the generated response length, preventing overly long output. However, be cautious as this might cut off responses mid-sentence.


Stream responses
With streaming, the model starts sending its response before it generates the complete output. This enables real-time processing of the output, and you can immediately update your user interface and perform other concurrent tasks.
Streaming enhances perceived responsiveness and creates a more interactive user experience.
For additional strategy you may also add an embedding to a vector database.
After you've generated your embedding you can add embeddings to a vector database, like Vector Search. This enables low-latency retrieval, and is critical as the size of your data increases.
To learn more about Vector Search, see Overview of Vector Search.

Great insights McMaco, I am using a vector db but the latency bottlencek has been the the embedding part . My main question was why the first call is long and if it caches something, what can I do to initialize the session so the embedding calls would br faster (warm start)

You may configure parameters having performance impact, these parameters can be set at index creation time and can affect recall, latency, availability, and cost when using Vector Search. This guidance applies to most cases. However, always experiment with your configurations to make sure that they work for your use case.
For parameter definitions, see Index configuration parameters.
